# Get rows which have a specific value occurring less than twice

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an issue with a SQL query. I have a table as below

```
EMPLOYEE_ID | STATUS
--------------------
    123         C
    234         S
    456         S
    123         C
    789         S
```

From the above table I need to get `EMPLOYEE_ID` which have occurrences with Status `C` appearing less than twice. Need help in figuring this out.

Comment: Can you show the query you are using now?

Comment: What is in this table ? what does each row represent? is the status an attribute of the employee, or of whatever each row in the table represents?  i.e., Could there also be a row in this table for EmployeeId 123 with a status 'S' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not Oracle, but see if you can use this.

```
Select Employee_ID
From table
Where Status = 'C'
Group By Employee_ID
Having Count(Status) < 2
```

Comment: Cheers! :) Worked perfectly